# Add binary file inside a class

Tags: c#, class, serialization, binary

I have Entity type class(Serializable, loaded and saved data at runtime) where user specified data is kept. There are several data types kept in class and I would like to add new Picture property as binary type. How to hold binary data in class, is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary data is best stored in a `byte[]`.